# SCTP Destination unreachable (protocol unreachable）

Tags: linux, sctp

when testing sctp msg communication between sender and reveiver in respective linux redhat VM , suddenly protocol unreachable for sender， then sender sending ABORT ICMP package t[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5igMM.png)o receiver and rebuild asssociation and back to nornal， as below said. thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some networking issue (maybe related to your VM). Basically the endpoint with IP address 10.107.89.144 cannot communicate to 10.107.89.131 for some reasons. You can see in your in wireshark trace that it failed to deliver data (there are some retransmissions in the log).
Try to change your VM network setting, say change it from NAT to bridge and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: thanks Alexander！ I cannot change VM network currently because we need find the root cause for product. I am confused that why it could recover and back to normal by abort and rebuild association if the network has some issue.